# Parquet partitioning degrades Int32 to float64

Tags: pandas, parquet, pyarrow

As you can see below, as soon as I partition the parquet dataset, my `Int32` type is read back as `float64`. This seems like a bug to me, as partitioning shouldn't change the datatype, and I loose all the advantages of the nullable int.

```
import pandas as pd # 1.0.4
import pyarrow as pa # 0.17.1
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, None, 1], 'b':['x']*4})
x.a = x.a.astype('Int32')
tbl = pa.Table.from_pandas(x)
pq.write_to_dataset(tbl, 'ok')
pq.write_to_dataset(tbl, 'busted', partition_cols=['b'])

print(pd.read_parquet('ok').dtypes['a'])  # Int32
print(pd.read_parquet('busted').dtypes['a'])  # float64
```

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-9134, this will be fixed in the upcoming pyarrow 1.0 release.